Analytic continuation of $\mathbb{R}$-analytic function

Let $A$ be a non-empty open set of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ an $\mathbb{R}$-analytic function ($Re(f)$; $Im(f)$ analytic functions).

Now, my goal is to find an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$  and an analytic function $F: U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $A \subset U \cap \mathbb{R}$ and that $F$ is an analytic continuation of $f$.
For each $x_0 \in A$, there exists $\epsilon_{x_0}$ such that for all $x \in (x_{0}-\epsilon_{x_0};x_{0} + \epsilon_{x_0})$
$$
Re(f(x))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n
$$
$$
Im(f(x))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(x-x_0)^n
$$
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n; \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(x-x_0)^n$ have radius of convergence $\geq \epsilon_{x_0}$
Now, I was thinking of the open set $U= \cup_{x_0 \in A} D(x_0,\epsilon_{x_0})$ and taking $F(x+yi)=f(x+yi)$; $F$'d be analytic; given $z_0 \in U$ , $F$ can be written as the sum of two absolutely convergent power series center ( one centered at $Re(z_0)$ and another at $Im(z_0$))  for $z \in D(z_0,\frac{\epsilon_{Re(z_0)}- |z_0|}{2})$ that could be rearranged as a single complex one centered at $z_0$. Is this valid? Is there a simpler way?

that's way too complicated; just take the power series around each point in $A$; it has a disc of convergence so extends to a complex analytic there; put it together and you get your extension
